# Multiple auth login does not redirect to the right link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I am enhancing a system with a user login present (for staffs) and I want to create another login instance for clients. 
So I have set up the guards and coded the rest as follows

```
// config/auth.php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],

        'client-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],

    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Client::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

```
// app/Client.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Client extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'clients';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

```
// routes/web.php

Route::prefix('/client')->name('client.')->namespace('Client')->group(function(){

    Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function(){
        //Login Routes
        Route::get('/login','LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        Route::post('/login','LoginController@login');
        Route::post('/logout','LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    });


    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

});
```

```
// app/Http/Controllers/Client/Auth/LoginController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Client\Auth;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('auth.client.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {
        $this->validator($request);

        if(Auth::guard('client')->attempt(['CustomerNo' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password],$request->filled('remember'))) {

            return redirect()
                ->intended(route('client.home'))
                ->with('status','You are Logged in as Admin!');
        }

        return $this->loginFailed();
    }

    private function validator(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'username'    => 'required|exists:clients,CustomerNo',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'username.exists' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
        ];

        $request->validate($rules,$messages);
    }

    private function loginFailed(){
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withInput()
            ->with('error','Login failed, please try again!');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('client')->logout();
        return redirect()
            ->route('client.login')
            ->with('status','You are logged out!');
    }
}
```

```
// app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php


namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {   
        if (Auth::guard('client')->check()) {
          return redirect('/client');
        } else {
          return redirect('/home');
        }

        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

```
// app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($guard == "client" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(route('client.home'));
        } 

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```
// app/Http/Controllers/Client/HomeController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Client;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:client');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('client.home');
    }
}
```

I have tried to login after finishing all this but it seems to keep redirecting me back to staff's (default user login) login page and a quick check at the session dd

```php
#session: Store {#195 ▼
      #id: "wQTohtl4aNaSZvYZ9ru3oqltcSqs4VhWb4SV42t2"
      #name: "portal_session"
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "_token" => "R6EyBlq0iNyfDh1V8Ogmta6U3uOhvJ0gcj7a2RMb"
        "url" => array:1 [▼
          "intended" => "https://mywebsite.com/home"
        ]
        "_flash" => array:2 [▼
          "old" => []
          "new" => []
        ]
        "_previous" => array:1 [▼
          "url" => "https://mywebsite.com/client/login"
        ]
        "login_client_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => 1
      ]
      #handler: FileSessionHandler {#194 ▼
        #files: Filesystem {#95}
        #path: "/home/mywebsite/storage/framework/sessions"
        #minutes: 1440
      }
      #started: true
    }
```

Is there any part where i did wrongly? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to solve  this but I have a personal opinion that I would like to share with you. if you make a role table wouldn't that be more efficient? so with a middleware or even in the controller you would check the role? I feel like you are doing something a few times repeatedly. even if this works if later you wanna update something it would be really time consuming

Comment: Thanks for replying and also for the advice. Yeah, I also thought it will be much easier for me to go the role route instead of this. But since this is the way that I have chosen to do this, might as well follow through it. I have solved this problem of mine, turns out the problems lies with another function that another coder did in the middleware that interfered with my codes above. I have made changes to it and it solved the problem.